# How to create a custom shape in android: Cross Over A Circle

Tags: java, android, drawable, draw, shapes

I want to draw a Circle and cross over this by using Shape drawable in android just like [image]

if anybody have idea how can it be achieved. Please help. I am not able to create Cross inside  Circle.

Answer (score 2):

> Use this one code

```
    class MyView extends View {
              Paint paint1 = new Paint();
            Paint paint2 = new Paint();
            Paint paint3 = new Paint();
            Paint paint4 = new Paint();
            Paint paint5 = new Paint();
            final RectF rect = new RectF();
             int mRadius = 130;
    @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
                // Example values
                rect.set(getWidth() / 2 - mRadius, getHeight() / 2 - mRadius,
                        getWidth() / 2 + mRadius, getHeight() / 2 + mRadius);
                paint1.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint1.setStrokeWidth(16);
                paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
                paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint2.setStrokeWidth(mRadius / 2);
                paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint2.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
                paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint3.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint3.setStrokeWidth(16);
                paint3.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint3.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
                paint3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 3600, false, paint1);

                canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2
                        - mRadius, getHeight() / 2 - mRadius, paint3);

                canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2
                        + mRadius, getHeight() / 2 - mRadius, paint3);

                canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2
                        - mRadius, getHeight() / 2 + mRadius, paint3);

                canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2
                        + mRadius , getHeight() / 2 + mRadius , paint3);
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version in **Kotlin**:

### X inside a circle

[image]

```
    paint.color = Color.WHITE
    canvas.drawOval(
        0F,
        0F,
        24F,
        24F,
        paint,
    )
    paint.color = Color.BLACK
    paint.strokeWidth = 7F
    canvas.drawLine(
        8F,
        8F,
        16F,
        16F,
        paint,
    )
    canvas.drawLine(
        16F,
        8F,
        8F,
        16F,
        paint,
    )
```